Terminology for extremal non-epimorphisms
Is there a special name for a morphism $f : X \to Y$ in a category which doesn't factor through any proper subobject of $Y$? In other words, we have $\mathrm{im}(f)=Y$ for the image of $f$.
This property is precisely what makes an epimorphism an extremal epimorphism. But the morphism $f$ is not necessarily an epimorphism. You can prove this when the category has equalizers, but not in general.
Ideas for a name in case no name exists in the literature (this is not part of my question since it is opinion-based, but I wanted to share these thoughts nevertheless to provide some context and examples):

extremal morphism. Sufficient for my needs but is confusing when applied to extremal monomorphisms. We cannot change history but coextremal epimorphism would actually be a better name for what we now call extremal epimorphism, and then coextremal morphism would probably be the best answer.
surjective morphism. This is because in every algebraic category it is precisely a surjective homomorphism. Also the equation $\mathrm{im}(f)=Y$ looks very much like surjectivity. On the other hand, one has to be careful with non-algebraic categories, see below.
dense morphism. This fits better to the example of the category of complete metric spaces, since the categorical image is the closure of the set-theoretical image.

The suggestion in the title (extremal non-epimorphism) is not really serious, it is not usable.

One cannot change history, but I think it would be reasonable to introduce the terminology "coextremal morphism" along with the explanation you have given. "Extremal monomorphism" appears to have been introduced in Isbell's Subobjects, adequacy, completeness and categories of algebras, and the term "extremal epimorphism" in Sonner's Canonical categories. I think it is reasonable to suggest that Sonner dualised the terminology inappropriately.

I prefer to reserve “surjection” for a pullback-stable property, since it is supposed to be local on the codomain and a morphism could satisfy the extremality condition “by accident” if there are not enough subobjects.

@varkor I disagree that extremal epimorphisms should be called "coextremal". They are extremal in exactly the same way that extremal monomorphisms are. They don't have the dual property to being extremal. The Arctic is in the extreme North of the planet, but the Antarctic is not in the coextreme South; it's in the extreme South.

@JeremyRickard I get your point. But this is not handled consistently. We have the notion of a cocommutative coalgebra for example.

@JeremyRickard: it is a common convention in category theory to dualise the adjectives as well as the nouns, e.g. cofiltered limits and filtered colimits. This is typically useful, rather than being redundant, for precisely the reason mentioned in the question: when considering generalisations, one may need to drop one of the words, but still wants to maintain a distinction between the two concepts.

@varkor I know it’s a common convention (or dually, a mmon nvention), but I think it’s a bad (and ugly) one. I think that mathematical terminology should be chosen to be descriptive, and if you start with “extremal monomorphism”, dualize it to “coextremal epimorphism”, and then detach the adjectives to apply them to more general morphisms, what happens? You end up with two terms “extremal morphism” and “coextremal morphism”, where which is which depends on what is pretty much the historical accident of whether “extremal” was first applied to monomorphisms or epimorphisms.

@JeremyRickard: I don't disagree, but that's the same for every categorical concept. Why are "limit" and "colimit" defined the way they are, rather than the other way around? Because someone made an arbitrary choice at some point, and the convention stuck. It would be better to have symmetric terminology, but it's difficult to change now.

@varkor Well, it's not the same for every categorical concept. E.g., monomorphism/epimorphism. But even for those that use the "co-" construction, the better ones have a root that indicates which way the arrows point: e.g., kernel/cokernel or well-powered/co-well-powered. I think limit/colimit is a particularly bad case, because not only did somebody make an arbitrary choice, but I would argue that they made the wrong arbitrary choice!

In Sketches of an Elephant this kind of morphism is called a cover (section A1.3).
In case you don't like that, here are some other possibilities (although I don't know that I actually like any of them):

codomain-extremal morphism.  Removes the ambiguity of which is "extremal" and which is "coextremal".
extremal pre-epimorphism.
just "extremal epimorphism", appealing to the red herring principle.  There's some precedent, at least: an effective epimorphism in an (∞,1)-category is not an epimorphism.


Thanks a lot, Mike! I will stick with "cover" in my paper then (even though I prefer "coextremal morphism" since it also dualizes well) because that is already used in print, and I don't want to introduce more confusion by creating a new name for the same thing. Even though the term "cover" for this kind of morphism is not used by many others (yet).

At some point I think the Elephant also dualizes "cover" to "cocover", possibly when talking about quasitoposes.

He missed the opportunity to talk about vers. (See also: mpact spaces, ntinuous function, ...)

@MartinBrandenburg To say nothing of nes.
